# Regular expression - remove last literal

Tags: regex, postgresql

So I have the following table in PostgreSQL.

This is a test table only with one column `route` that has values of route names like

```
I-95
US-95N
I-95 S
```

I want to remove the trailing direction literals from all the route names.

```
UPDATE <schema>.<table>
SET route=  regexp_replace(route, '%[:digit:](S|N|E|W)', '%[:digit:]', 'ig');
```

No change in the records happens. Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be good form to supply some sample values and expected results. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove any single letter signifying a cardinal direction following immediately after a digit:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    route = regexp_replace(route, '(\d)[SNEW]', '\1', 'ig')
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3975)

A *positive lookbehind match* would be even more elgant, but sadly only [*lookahead matches*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE) are implemented. So I use a [*back-reference*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-BACKREF-TABLE) to re-insert the first (captured) part from the match.

The [*bracket expression*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE) `[SNEW]` is simpler for the case than multiple branches <strike>`(S|N|E|W)`</strike>, which would need [*non-capturing parentheses*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE) in this case: `(:?S|N|E|W)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am fairly new to regular expressions. Appreciate the links as well :)

Comment: @dahvyah: Added one more to clarify.

Comment: So I came across some more values for US Routes for which I am unable to remove teh strings in parenthesis..example values below :

`US-190N (Fairfax County)  
US-190 (Fairfax COunty)`

I just want to store US-190 for both the above records. I tried variations of your code in the SQL Fiddle link you had provided, but its not working. COuld you please suggest how I could work this out as well?

Comment: @dahvyah: Start a **new question** for your new question - with the necessary details. You can always link to this one for context.